# How pandas process boolean statements inside a pandas frame object

Tags: python, pandas

Wondering how Pandas process the following statement internally please.

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({'classNumber': [2, 4], 'center x': [2, 0], 'center y': [4, 4]})
```

The output of `test`:

[image]

```
test.loc[test['classNumber'] == 2, 'center y'] = '5'
```

The output of `test` after operation:

[image]

**Question**: so is this how pandas work here: once it sees that `test.loc` has a boolean statement, it will pass it to a function that will return all rows whose `test['classNumber'] == 2` then it will assign those rows' column `test['center y']` with the new value 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely! The function `df.loc[condition, 'column_name']` will locate rows where `condition == True` in the column `df['column_name']`.